# Get rotated rectangle UIView corners' coordinates iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, uigesturerecognizer

I'm trying to find a rotated rectangle UIView's four corners' coordinates.

I think one way I can do is to use recognizer.rotation, find the rotated angle then calculate the origins. But that requires some geometry calculation.

```
- (IBAction)handlePan:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
    NSLog(@"Rotation in degrees since last change: %f", [recognizer rotation] * (180 / M_PI));
    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.rotation);
    NSLog(@"%@",recognizer);

    recognizer.rotation = 0;
    NSLog(@"bound is %f and %f, frame is %f and %f, %f and %f.",recognizer.view.bounds.size.width,recognizer.view.bounds.size.height, recognizer.view.frame.size.width,recognizer.view.frame.size.height, recognizer.view.frame.origin.x, recognizer.view.frame.origin.y);
}
```

I'm just wondering if there are any other easier ways to get the coordinates?
Thanks!

EDIT:

Looks like we have a great answer here(see answer below). I have managed to calculate the corners through a stupid way -- using rotation angle and geometry. It works but not easy and light. I'm sharing my code here just in case some one may want to use it(Even though I doubt it.)

```
    float r = 100;
    NSLog(@"radius is %f.",r);
    float AAngle = M_PI/3+self.rotatedAngle;
    float AY = recognizer.view.center.y - sin(AAngle)*r;
    float AX = recognizer.view.center.x - cos(AAngle)*r;
    self.pointPADA = CGPointMake(AX, AY);
    NSLog(@"View Center is (%f,%f)",recognizer.view.center.x,recognizer.view.center.y);
    NSLog(@"Point A has coordinate (%f,%f)",self.pointPADA.x,self.pointPADA.y);

    float BAngle = M_PI/3-self.rotatedAngle;
    float BY = recognizer.view.center.y - sin(BAngle)*r;
    float BX = recognizer.view.center.x + cos(BAngle)*r;
    self.pointPADB = CGPointMake(BX, BY);
    NSLog(@"Point B has coordinate (%f,%f)",BX,BY);

    float CY = recognizer.view.center.y + sin(AAngle)*r;
    float CX = recognizer.view.center.x + cos(AAngle)*r;
    self.pointPADC = CGPointMake(CX, CY);
    NSLog(@"Point C has coordinate (%f,%f)",CX,CY);

    float DY = recognizer.view.center.y + sin(BAngle)*r;
    float DX = recognizer.view.center.x - cos(BAngle)*r;
    self.pointPADD = CGPointMake(DX, DY);
    NSLog(@"Point D has coordinate (%f,%f)",DX,DY);
```

Comment: How you took value of r = 100?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's my solution though I wonder if there's a more succinct way:

```
CGPoint originalCenter = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(theView.center,
    CGAffineTransformInvert(theView.transform));

CGPoint topLeft = originalCenter;
topLeft.x -= theView.bounds.size.width / 2;
topLeft.y -= theView.bounds.size.height / 2;
topLeft = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(topLeft, theView.transform);

CGPoint topRight = originalCenter;
topRight.x += theView.bounds.size.width / 2;
topRight.y -= theView.bounds.size.height / 2;
topRight = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(topRight, theView.transform);

CGPoint bottomLeft = originalCenter;
bottomLeft.x -= theView.bounds.size.width / 2;
bottomLeft.y += theView.bounds.size.height / 2;
bottomLeft = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(bottomLeft, theView.transform);

CGPoint bottomRight = originalCenter;
bottomRight.x += theView.bounds.size.width / 2;
bottomRight.y += theView.bounds.size.height / 2;
bottomRight = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(bottomRight, theView.transform);
```

Comment: I added topLeft.x += self.mainImageView.transform.tx; and topLeft.y += self.mainImageView.transform.ty; after topLeft = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(topLeft, theView.transform); for views that translate as well as scale and rotate.

Answer (score 1):

Checked answer in Swift

```
struct ViewCorners {
    private(set) var topLeft:     CGPoint!
    private(set) var topRight:    CGPoint!
    private(set) var bottomLeft:  CGPoint!
    private(set) var bottomRight: CGPoint!

    private let originalCenter: CGPoint
    private let transformedView: UIView

    private func pointWith(multipliedWidth: CGFloat, multipliedHeight: CGFloat) -> CGPoint {
        var x = originalCenter.x
        x += transformedView.bounds.width  / 2 * multipliedWidth

        var y = originalCenter.y
        y += transformedView.bounds.height / 2 * multipliedHeight

        var result = CGPoint(x: x, y: y).applying(transformedView.transform)
        result.x += transformedView.transform.tx
        result.y += transformedView.transform.ty

        return result
    }

    init(view: UIView) {
        transformedView = view
        originalCenter = view.center.applying(view.transform.inverted())

        topLeft =     pointWith(multipliedWidth:-1, multipliedHeight:-1)
        topRight =    pointWith(multipliedWidth: 1, multipliedHeight:-1)
        bottomLeft =  pointWith(multipliedWidth:-1, multipliedHeight: 1)
        bottomRight = pointWith(multipliedWidth: 1, multipliedHeight: 1)

    }
}
```

Then create struct instance and take transformed rect corners new points.

```
let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 40, y: 20, width: 100, height: 50))
view.transform = .init(rotationAngle: .pi / 4)
let corners = ViewCorners(view: view)
print(corners.topLeft,
      corners.topRight,
      corners.bottomLeft,
      corners.bottomRight,
      separator: "\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Swift 4, We can get the bounds of rotated view by simple way.

let transformedBounds = view.bounds.applying(view.transform)